# Menu item wont align right

Tags: php, html, css, menu

Hey I am making a menu for a website for a project I am doing and I couldn't get the Menu item "Login" to align right. I would appreciate it if someone would help me. Also I would be happy to give you any other parts of the code you need. Thanks Joshua

CSS Code

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.title-box {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.title-box a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    background-color: #42444f;
    /*margin:20px 10px 0 10px;*/
    margin: 0;
    color: #acadb1;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.header_left_box {
    float: left;
}

.header_right_box {
    float: right;
}

.header a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.header li.active a,
.header li.active:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2c2f3b;
}

.header li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.content {
    padding: 45px 35px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.content a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #2C2F3B;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #42444f;
    color: #acadb1;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    margin: 0;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.feedback {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.feedback.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
}
.feedback.success {
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
}

ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul#menu {
}

ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu li {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
ul#menu li:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul#menu li a {
    color: #acadb1;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
ul#menu li.active ul a {
    color: #acadb1;
}


ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #42444f;
}

ul#menu li.active ul.sub-menu {
    background-color: #2c2f3b;
}

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}


ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;

}

.header .namebox {
    float: right;
    background-color: #1e2029;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header .avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

input, select, textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #2C2F3B;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.remember-me-checkbox {
    float: left; min-width: 0; margin: 3px 10px 15px 0;
}
.remember-me-label {
    float:left; min-width: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #888;
}
.login-submit-button {
    float: none; clear: both;
}

.login-form-password-pattern-reminder {
    display: block;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;

}

.login-default-box,
.login-facebook-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

a.facebook-login-button,
a.facebook-register-button {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

a.facebook-login-button:hover,
a.facebook-register-button:hover {
    background-color: #2f477a;
}

.register-default-box,
.register-facebook-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.clear-both {
    clear: both;
}

.debug-helper-box {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {

    .header_left_box,
    .header .avatar {
        float: none;
    }

    .header_right_box {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1E2029;
    }

    ul#menu li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    ul#menu li a {
        display: block;
    }

    ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
    }

    ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li {
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #4a4c55;
    }
    ul#menu li.active ul.sub-menu li {
        background-color: #2C2F3B;
    }

    ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

}

.avatar img {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
            border: 1px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
} tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
} tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
} tr:hover td{
    background-color:#ffffff;


}
 td{
    vertical-align:middle;

    background-color:#ffffff;

    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
} tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
} tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
} tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
 tr:first-child td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #ff0000 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #ff0000) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #ff0000 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff7f00', endColorstr='#ff0000');  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff7f00,ff0000);

    background-color:#ff7f00;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}
 tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff7f00 5%, #ff0000 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #ff0000) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #ff0000 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff7f00', endColorstr='#ff0000');  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff7f00,ff0000);

    background-color:#ff7f00;
}
 tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
 tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

Menu Code

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Login</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>application/libs/css/reset.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>application/libs/css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL; ?>application/libs/js/application.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <div class='title-box'>
        <img src=''>
        </div>


    <div class="header">

        <div class="header_left_box">

        <ul id="menu">

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "index")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>forum/">Forum</a>
            </li>

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "helpcenter")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>helpcenter/">Help Center</a>
            </li>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true):?>

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "dashboard")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>dashboard/">Dashboard</a>
            </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true):?>

                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/showprofile">My Account</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/changeaccounttype">Change account type</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/uploadavatar">Upload an avatar</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/editusername">Edit my username</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/edituseremail">Edit my email</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/changepassword">Edit my password</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/logout">Logout</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 1):?>

                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 2):?>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher/index">Teacher</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 3):?>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher/index">Teacher</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "admin")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>admin/index">Admin</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "admin")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>admin/index"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == false):?>
                <li class='right' <?php if ($this->checkForActiveControllerAndAction($filename, "login/index")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/">Login</a>
                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </ul>

        </div>

        <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true): ?>

            <div class="header_right_box">

                <div class="namebox">
                    Hello <?php echo Session::get('user_name'); ?>!
                </div>

                <div class="avatar">

                    <?php if (USE_GRAVATAR) { ?>

                        <img src='<?php echo Session::get('user_gravatar_image_url'); ?>'

                             style='width:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px; height:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px;' />

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <img src='<?php echo Session::get('user_avatar_file'); ?>'

                             style='width:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px; height:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px;' />

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clear-both"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle without php

Comment: I will do that i will post it in 5-10 min

Comment: it doesn't work in jsfiddle it comes out not horizontal. If you have anything else tell me

Comment: Replace your php with actual text/html and you should be fine.

Comment: it opens in mobile view so it doesnt work

Comment: Please provide a demo of your code without PHP. We can't 100% help until we can see the code.

Comment: i know it will only open in mobile view if you want i can give u my webiste url

Comment: never mind i worked it out here is url: http://jsfiddle.net/gTU37/

Comment: I think you might need to restructure your code in order for this to work efficiently

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/gTU37/1/

Comment: Please review your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float:right` to `ul#menu`

```
ul#menu {
float:right;
}
```

If it'll not work then I have to see some working demo of your code.

**UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/fL3tG/

I think I got the issue. Your code is:-

```
 <div class="header_left_box">
    Your menu is here I think
 </div>
 <div class="header_right_box">
    //Your other code
 </div>
```

**AND**

Your CSS is:-

```
.header_left_box {
    float: left;
}

.header_right_box {
    float: right;
}
```

It shows that div containing your Menu will be on left side. You have to inter-change the classes of both the divs or you can take your menu our of this div `<div class="header_left_box">`

Remove width: 100%; from this:-

```
ul#menu li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header_left_box {  }

ul#menu li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

As I stated earlier, you need to restructure your menu code for this to work. This works http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/MVzR7/

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your css menu field:

```
float:right;
```

Comment: use this in your HTML file under header leftbox div. Its working, i checked.
<ul id="menu" align="right">